# Suppress errors in Symfony 2

Tags: forms, symfony, event-listener

I try to remove some fields from form in event listener. But when I do that I get an error like `this form should not contain extra fields`. How can I suppress this error?

Here is my listener:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $form->remove('field');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to ignore data submitted for a field you could unset it's data on "PRE_SET_DATA" or set it to current value in the entity.

Not sure why you would like to first allow the user to submit a form and then cut out part of it instead of just presenting a shorter form in the first place

you could also unset the data AND remove the field from the form on PRE_SUBMIT, but then in case vlaidation goes wrong, user gets back a different form

Comment: look, I has a checkbox, if I set it checked i need to show part of form. But i can read this value only on PRE_SUBMIT, because on PRE_SET DATA  `$event->getData()` returns `null`

Comment: then as i wrote at the end of my answer, use PRE_SUBMIT and remove the form field AND uset proper fields in the submitted data

Comment: how I can unset this fields? I think php `unset()` inappropriate here?

Comment: $data = $event->getData();
    if (isset($data['mobile'])) {
        unset($data['mobile']);
    }
    $event->setData($data);